# How is the Toda bracket affected by choice of nullhomotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology

(The bulk of my post is Question #2) I would like to understand the *Toda bracket*, which I learned about in Hatcher $\S$4.2, p. 387.

[image]

In particular, I want to understand how exactly it varies depending on the choices of nullhomotopies.

> Question 1: is the Toda bracket homotopy invariant w.r.t. $f$? I ask because I do not think the cone functor is homotopy invariant, and $Cf$ is part of the construction.

Hatcher has an exercise for this in this case of homotopy groups of spheres:

[image]

I begin by choosing $N>i+j+k+1$, so that we can represent our elements as
$$f:S^{N+i+j+k} \to S^{N+j+k},$$
$$g:S^{N+j+k} \to S^{N+k},$$
$$h:S^{N+j} \to S^N.$$
As part of the definition of the Toda bracket, $g \circ f$ and $h \circ g$ are nullhomotopic. Any nullhomotopy corresponds to a map from the cone on the domain to the space.

To start, fix $G:CS^{N+j+k} \cong D^{N+j+k+1} \to S^N$ to be the map corresponding to some nullhomotopy $G$ from $h\circ g$ to the constant map. **I want to understand** how different choices of nullhomotopies of $g \circ f$ affect $\langle f, g, h \rangle$.

> Question 2: How do different choices of nullhomotopies $F,F'$ from $g \circ f$ to the constant map affect the Toda bracket?

Geometrically, I vaguely think this has to do with 'how many ways can we pull $gf$ to a point through $CS^{N+i+j+k}$,' which should be responsible for the subgroup $h \pi_{i+j+1}^s$. But I do not know where the $+1$ comes from, or how to formalize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the Toda bracket $\langle h, g, f \rangle$ indeed "only" depends on the homotopy classes of $f$, $g$, and $h$.

Here is a somewhat pedantic answer to your second question.  The Toda bracket should be defined as a *subset* of $[\Sigma W, Z]$ consisting of all the maps you can get from the construction described by Hatcher as you vary over all the nullhomotopies of $gf$ and $hg$.  Therefore, I would say that the Toda bracket (as a subset) trivially does not depend on the choices of nullhomotopies.

Of course, Hatcher is using "Toda bracket" in a slightly different way, to refer to a particular map you get after selecting specific choices of nullhomotopies.  If you're wondering about how to go about showing the exercise Hatcher gives about the indeterminacy, here is a sketch of the argument.  Consider the set of nullhomotopies of $gf$.  It is a torsor for $[\Sigma W, Y]$.  To see this, think of a nullhomotopy as a map $CW \to Y$, and if you have two such maps you can glue the cones along $W$ to get a map $\Sigma W \to Y$.  Conversely, given a nullhomotopy $CW \to Y$ and a map $\Sigma W \to Y$, you can glue one of the double cones in $\Sigma W$ to cancel out $CW$, and you're left with a new map $CW \to Y$.  Therefore, one source of indeterminacy comes from $h_* [\Sigma W, Y]$.  Arguing analogously for the nullhomotopy of $hg$, we have another indeterminacy coming from $f^* [\Sigma X, Z]$.  Therefore altogether the indeterminacy is given by the subgroup $f^* [\Sigma X, Z] + h_* [\Sigma W, Y] \subseteq [\Sigma W, Z]$, and the Toda bracket is a coset of this subgroup.